# C# Convert HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, save

Использую библиотеку **Chromehtmltopdf**. Проблема заключается в том, что код (который был написан в примере в github) не работает... 
Кто знает как его завести? Другие библиотеки не вариант использовать, так как они криво конвертируют сайты (кроме Spire.pdf, но он платный и не всегда поддерживает svg формат изображения)

КОД С#:

> using ChromeHtmlToPdfLib;

```
SaveFileDialog opf2 = new SaveFileDialog();
opf2.Filter = "HTML (Результат) (*.html)|*.html";
opf2.ShowDialog();

using (var converter = new Converter())
{
converter.ConvertToPdf(Convert.ToString(opf2.FileName), Convert.ToString(opf2.FileName + ".pdf"));
}
// Show the PDF
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(opf2.FileName + ".pdf");
}
```

Github источник: https://github.com/Sicos1977/ChromeHtmlToPdf

Мне нужен именно эта библиотека, так как, только браузеры могут правильно конвертировать мой сайт. А на сколько я понял, то эта библиотека берёт за основу как раз функцию из Chrome (один из проверенных браузеров).

Ошибка:

> CS1501    Ни одна из перегрузок метода "ConvertToPdf" не принимает 2 аргументов.

Comment: Помню была библиотека, что то типа pdfsharp, точное название не скажу (с телефона не удобно гуглить). Попробуйте поискать, может вам подойдет.

Comment: Я пробовал, он не выводит svg изображение и не выводит таблицы (таблица без границ выводится)